# Does Debian 5 have augeas version 1.0

Tags: debian-based, augeas

I am new to augeas and I want to find out if Debian 5 or my OS supports augeas version 1.0 or higher.

How can I do this?

Comment: FYI, Debian 5 (aka Lenny) has been EOL since 2012…

Comment: Sure, but I still have it on a old computer. Are you saying that augeas won't run on it ?

Comment: http://www.cs.rug.nl/~jurjen/ApprenticesNotes/ch27s07.html says that Augeas is available in Debian from Lenny